# What type of function is this? I need to calculate k.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following equation represents a relationship between two concentrations of species in a chemical reaction:

$[C] = (1 - e^{-kt}) [A]$.

I have values for $t$ and $[C]$ and need to calculate $k$ presumably from plotting a function.

If I take the natural log of the function does it make:

$\ln[C] = -kt + \ln[A]$.

If so I could plot $\ln[C]$ against $t$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset the equations more clearly. Also, please define what C and A are. Are they matrices, or ... ?

Comment: [A] and [C] are concentrations of species in a chemical reaction so just numbers

Comment: Your plan of plotting $\ln[C]$ against $t$ is the correct one. Then you can add a trendline (that is, use linear regression to do a least-squares fit) on your data, and the slope of the resulting line will be $-k.$

Comment: I'm unsure that I have taken the natural log correctly, because I'm not sure if I could take Ln1 out of the bracket

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is a little unclear. Do you mean $[C]=(1-e^{-kt})[A]$?

If so, then you can solve for $k$ as follows:

$$[C]=(1-e^{-kt})[A]$$
$$[C]/[A]=1-e^{-kt}$$
$$1-\frac {[C]}{[A]}=e^{-kt}$$
$$\ln\left(1-\frac {[C]}{[A]}\right)=-kt$$
$$k=-\frac 1t \ln\left(1-\frac {[C]}{[A]}\right)$$

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I need to put my experimental data into this function. I have measured [C] as a function of time (t) and need to calculate k. I dont have [A], but [A] and [C] are related through this function

Comment: Okay. But I don't see how you can estimate $k$ if you don't also have empirical values for $[A]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$\ln(C)-\ln(A)=-kt$$
$$t=-\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\frac{C}{A}\right)$$